# How to see log of nmcli "Network connection failed :unknown reason"

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, pptp

My country has network block, so when i use "nmcli connection up uuid", it always show "connection establish successful" and then show "Network connection failed :unknown reason:" right now, I find [network mannager](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man5/NetworkManager.conf.5.html) can config log, **my question is** where is network manager log?

fortunately, when i use linux mint gui to enable vpn(network manager gui > vpn connections > my vpn) it work well.

**update**, please don't tell me try to use openvpn, my country has blocked this way since too many people use it.